# Is there a word for "making oneself certain again"?

Tags: verbs, antonyms

If I am uncertain of something and later I made myself certain again, is there a single word to express that?

Example:

"I was uncertain whether the result was correct. But I `re-certained` myself by double checking my calculations."

Comment: I would say "deluded".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the word **reassure**, about which the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reassure) says

> **reassure**
>   VERB
>
> Say or do something to remove the doubts or fears of (someone)
>
> *She's planning to be a volunteer teacher; it reassures me to know she's got such great aspirations.*

So you can say

> I reassured myself by double checking my calculations.

Comment: "...but I double-checked my calculations to **confirm** that it was correct."

Answer (score 0):

As in:

*"I was uncertain whether the result was correct. But I **satisfied** myself by double checking my calculations."*

**satisfy**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/satisfy)

> - a. To free from doubt or question; convince:
> - b. To provide sufficient explanation to dispel or answer (a doubt or    question).

Answer (score 0):

“Verified.”

"I was uncertain whether the result was correct. But I verified my results by double checking my calculations."

Comment: The thing is, you can use "verify" for the results, which you did by altering the sentence to say "verified my results". But since the question is about the word "myself", the word "verify" is not really applicable, since you cannot really "verify yourself".

Comment: Sometimes what English learners are looking for simply doesn’t exist in English the way that it does in their native tongue.  So no, I didn’t directly address the reference to “myself,” but I did give the author something they could use to express something quite similar which they can immediately use to express themselves and be understood.